# Why does an arrow disappear at some angles in HTML Canvas when I use lineJoin = "round"?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am facing a weird bug in HTML Canvas. I want to draw an arrow but it disappears when I add `ctx.lineJoin = "round"`  for some coordinates. Here is the MCVE:

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById('scene') as HTMLCanvasElement

    // canvas sizing
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    if (ctx === null) { console.error(`ctx is ${ctx}`); return }

    canvas.width = 512
    canvas.height = 512

    let from = {x:317, y:166}
    let to = {x:439, y:56}
    let arrowHeadSize = 20
    let arrowFinsAngle = Math.PI/6
    let path = new Path2D()
    
    // arrow body
    path.moveTo(from.x, from.y)
    path.lineTo(to.x, to.y)

    // arrow head
    let radians_to = Math.atan2(to.y - from.y, to.x - from.x)
    
    path.moveTo(to.x, to.y);
    path.lineTo(to.x - arrowHeadSize * Math.cos(radians_to - arrowFinsAngle), to.y - arrowHeadSize * Math.sin(radians_to - arrowFinsAngle));
    path.moveTo(to.x, to.y);
    path.lineTo(to.x - arrowHeadSize * Math.cos(radians_to + arrowFinsAngle), to.y - arrowHeadSize * Math.sin(radians_to + arrowFinsAngle));

    path.closePath()

    ctx.lineWidth = 4
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white"
    ctx.lineCap = "round"
    ctx.lineJoin = "round" //works if I remove this line
    ctx.stroke(path)
```

This bug occurs in the Chrome browser but not in Firefox.

[image: arrow bug in Chrome]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console when the arrow disappears? The code you shared displays an arrow in chrome and firefox: codepen.io/jwdunn/pen/dyaeWXz

Comment: @JamesWilliamDunn No there are no errors in the console. I don't see any arrow in the codepen URL you gave (I tried in another laptop too) in Chrome. But the arrow appears if I change the `from` and `to` coordinates and also if I comment the `ctx.lineJoin = "round"` line

Comment: Can't repro in 119.0.6045.159 on macOS. What version of Chrome are you using? They were recently playing with empty closed path so this could have affected it. 2 more things to check on your side: Does the issue still happen when you comment out the `path.closePath()` line? Does the issue still happen when you initialize your context with `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true })`?

Comment: @Manik Following up on my previous comment, Chrome version 109.0.5414.120 displays the arrow without any changes. However, Chrome 119.0.6045.159 on macOS, the arrow does not display until I comment out the `ctx.lineJoin` line. Perhaps this is a Chrome issue/glitch.

Comment: @JamesWilliamDunn yes and it works if I comment out either one of the `ctx.lineJoin = "round"` or `ctx.lineCap = "round"` This is a serious bug. It would be nice if someone can provide a workaround for now till they fix the glitch

Comment: Making separate Paths for the body and the head of the arrow and then calling `ctx.stroke(body)` and `ctx.stroke(head)` is one workaround to this problem

Comment: @Kaiido yes the issue goes away if we add `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true })`

Comment: So the issue is with the GPU renderer... Very weird I can't reproduce on my Chrome on macOS though... You can open an issue at https://crbug.com